# Updating a table in Excel when a new line is added

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have a problem and I find it very hard to explain, but here goes:

I have an excel sheet in which one of my employees needs to enter his data.

This data is used to calculate an average value (among other things)

[image: namloos]

I have made this part of my sheet a table, to make it easier to have those  "sort alphabetically" buttons.

What I would like is this: the table should be just 1 row by default. When the mechanic enters the first fiber values in the top row, the sheet does its calculating, etc., and then adds another (table) row, along with the formulas and layout required in the table.

Is this possible?

I have added the vba tag, because it might be unavoidable to use vba code for this.

Comment: You should be able to resize the table to just one row. There a small triangle mark in the lower right cell; select and drag it up to the first row; then just copy over the rows below with a blank row. You should then be good to go.

Comment: Theres no triangle :(

Comment: Okay. With cell in table selected, choose Resize Table from the Design section of the Table Tools tab on the ribbon. Then change the table range to two rows (header and 1 entry row). Erase any formulas that are left outside the table after the resize.

Comment: @chuff You should combine your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to resize the table to just one row. There a small triangle mark in the lower right cell; select and drag it up to the first row; then just copy over the rows below with a blank row.

[image: initial table]

This can also be accomplished with commands from the ribbon. After selecting a cell in the table with your mouse, choose `Resize Table` from the `Design` section of the `Table Tools` tab on the ribbon.

[image: resizing the table]

Then, change the table range to two rows (header and 1 entry row).

You can erase any formulas that are left outside the table after the resizing.

[image: erasing formulas outside the table]

The table (and the formulas in its column) will automatically expand when you make another entry at the bottom of the table.

[image: adding an entry at the bottom of the table]